# What is the similar code of jquery's $('#something') in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am getting different console output for  $('#list') and document.getElementById("list")

My console print is given below.

```
console.log($('#list'));

console.log(document.getElementById("list"));
```

But output in console shows different.

```
[select#list.form-control]

<select id="list" class="form-control" size="10"><option>PHP</option><option>JavaScript</option></select>
```

but i need same output in javascript like jquery.

Comment: The jQuery's result is an array of the 2nd types of result. Try running this in the console: `console.log($('#list')[0]);`

Comment: Try $(document.getElementById("list"))

Answer (score 4):

The difference is because `$('#list')` returns a [jQuery object](http://api.jquery.com/Types/#jQuery) and `document.getElementById("list")` returns an [Element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element).

If you need to get the Element from a jQuery object, access it by index, or use `get()`. All of the below will give the same output of an Element object:

```
console.log($('#list').get(0));
console.log($('#list')[0]);
console.log(document.getElementById("list"));
```

If you want to return a jQuery object use any of these:

```
console.log($('#list'));
console.log($(document.getElementId('list'));
```

Note however that the second example in this case is entirely redundant and is only included for completeness.

Comment: From what I can understand, OP want an output in javascript like he gets in jquery and not the other way around

Comment: This eventually means that it is not entirelly possible to get a jquery object in javascript  without using jquery :). Am I correct

Comment: That's correct. You could create your own class to mimic a jQuery object, but that's pretty pointless - you may as well just use jQuery itself

Answer (score 3):

This is to be expected, jQuery returns the DOM node wrapped in a jQuery object with jQuery methods, while native methods like `getElementById` will just return the DOM node.

If you wanted the DOM node, you could do

```
console.log($('#list').get(0));
```

There's no way to return a jQuery object without jQuery though, and doing

```
$(document.getElementById("list"))
```

is pointless, however if you already have a native DOM node, you can just wrap it in jQuery -> `$(element)`